# jquery selector for div that contains specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to select the DIV of the first row in the offers table on this page that is shipped by Amazon Prime.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B00NMND7AW/?condition=new

So in this example the row I'm trying to select with jQuery is the one that is £25.19

I have tried the following:

```
div.olpOffer .a-icon-prime:first
```

This gets me only so far. Now I need to figure out how to select the div that contains that.

I need to be able to paste this into the Selector Gadget plugin for Chrome and it should select the div that contains the cheapest Amazon Prime item.

Comment: are you searching for `.parent()`?
`$('div.olpOffer .a-icon-prime:first').parent()`
is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```
$('.olpOffer:has(.a-icon-prime):first');
```

This will select the first `.olpOffer` element that has an element with a class of `.a-icon-prime`.

Comment: This works!! I was trying for ages to fix this! :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Nothing wrong I just like mine better :) reading it makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
$(".supersaver").closest("div.olpOffer")
```

It selects the row:

```html
<div class="a-row a-spacing-mini olpOffer">
  <div class="a-column a-span2">

    <span class="a-size-large a-color-price olpOfferPrice a-text-bold">            £25.19            </span>
    <span class="a-color-price">
            
        </span>
    <span class="supersaver"><i class="a-icon a-icon-prime" aria-label="Amazon Prime TM"><span class="a-icon-alt">Amazon Prime TM</span>
    </i>
    </span>


    <p class="olpShippingInfo">
      <span class="a-color-secondary">
                Eligible for FREE UK Delivery <a href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=mk_gship_olp?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=200039400&amp;pop-up=1" target="SuperSaverShipping" onclick="return amz_js_PopWin('/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=mk_gship_olp?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=200039400&amp;pop-up=1','SuperSaverShipping','width=550,height=550,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=0,status=0');">Details</a>

        </span>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="a-column a-span3">


    <div class="a-section a-spacing-small">
      <span class="a-size-medium olpCondition a-text-bold">
            New
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="a-column a-span2 olpSellerColumn">
    <h3 class="a-spacing-none olpSellerName">
            <img alt="Amazon.co.uk" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/01pSGAIMN3L.gif" width="90" height="19">
</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="a-column a-span3 olpDeliveryColumn">
    <p class="a-spacing-mini olpAvailability">
    </p>
    <ul class="a-vertical">
      <li class="olpFastTrack"><span class="a-list-item">
            In stock.  









<span id="ftm_us7UeOB4c9pZTmqq2Md4WubIlhxKT3k9uiwFnsOOTz6eaIxF2ReWmql9mIaXr5EWHB9hdFWHF3jDdpJB7I6iPIEhJZbrPX5z">Want delivery by Thursday, 3 December?




<span id="shippingMessage_ftinfo_olp_1">Order it in the next <span id="ftc_us7UeOB4c9pZTmqq2Md4WubIlhxKT3k9uiwFnsOOTz6eaIxF2ReWmql9mIaXr5EWHB9hdFWHF3jDdpJB7I6iPIEhJZbrPX5z" style="color: #006600;">19 hours and 10 minutes</span>, and choose <b>One-Day Delivery</b> at
        checkout.
        </span>






        <a href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=ftinfo_olp_1?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=200275230&amp;pop-up=1" target="_blank" onclick="return amz_js_PopWin('/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=ftinfo_olp_1?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=200275230&amp;pop-up=1','_blank','width=750,height=600,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=1,status=1');">See details</a>

        </span>

        </span>
      </li>





      <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=olp_merch_ship_1?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=492868">Domestic delivery rates</a>
                 and <a href="/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=olp_merch_return_1?ie=UTF8&amp;nodeId=502480">return policy</a>.
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <p></p>








  </div>
  <div class="a-column a-span2 olpBuyColumn a-span-last">













    <div class="a-button-stack">
      <form method="post" action="/gp/item-dispatch/ref=olp_atc_new_1" class="a-spacing-none">
        <input type="hidden" name="session-id" value="275-2613291-9295018">
        <input type="hidden" name="qid">
        <input type="hidden" name="sr">
        <input type="hidden" name="signInToHUC" value="0" id="signInToHUC">
        <input type="hidden" name="metric-asin.B00NMND7AW" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="registryItemID.1">
        <input type="hidden" name="registryID.1">
        <input type="hidden" name="itemCount" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="offeringID.1" value="us7UeOB4c9pZTmqq2Md4WubIlhxKT3k9uiwFnsOOTz6eaIxF2ReWmql9mIaXr5EWHB9hdFWHF3jDdpJB7I6iPIEhJZbrPX5z">
        <input type="hidden" name="isAddon" value="0">

        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="olp-click-log" data-olp-click-log="{&quot;subtype&quot;:&quot;main&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;addToCart&quot;}">
                      <span class="a-button a-button-normal a-spacing-micro a-button-primary a-button-icon" id="a-autoid-6"><span class="a-button-inner"><i class="a-icon a-icon-cart"></i><input name="submit.addToCart" class="a-button-input" type="submit" value="Add to Basket" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-6-announce"><span class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true" id="a-autoid-6-announce">
                          Add to Basket
                      </span></span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </form>

      <div class="a-section a-spacing-micro a-text-center">
        or
      </div>
      <p class="a-spacing-none a-text-center olpSignIn">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/utility/edit-one-click-pref.html/ref=olp_offerlisting_1?ie=UTF8&amp;returnPath=%2Fgp%2Foffer-listing%2FB00NMND7AW">Sign in</a> to turn on 1-Click ordering.
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That will select multiple elements (since there is more than one `.supersaver` element on the page. You might want to chain `.first()` in order to select the first match `$(".supersaver").closest("div").first()`. Or event just `$(".supersaver:first").closest("div")`

Comment: Seems it works for this page `$(".supersaver").closest("div.olpOffer")`